# Всегда ли выполняется скрипт PHP до конца?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, у нас есть PHP скрипт ,цикл выполняющиеся раз в 10 мин.
То есть в цикле стоит таймер на 10 мин и он выполняется всего 3 раза.
Получается скрипт выполняется всего 30 мин.
Но если клиент откроет этот скрипт и закроет его через 5 мин, он будет выполнятся сам до конца или сразу же прекратит свою работу?
А если в начале стоит подключение к БД ,а в самом конце (после цикла) закрытие соединения с БД ,оно же закроет его если даже клиент закроет эту страницу?

Comment: Не городите велосипеды. Уберите цикл, сделайте только одинарный запуск и запускайте скрипт по cron.

Comment: Суть не в этом.Мне главное понять он будет выполнятся или нет.Не важно цикл там или что то другое, если клиент закрывает страницу, он выполняется до конца или нет?

Comment: @Mr_Epic будет! Тема исчерпана?

Comment: Попробуй в теле цикла писать текущию итерацию в БД, запусти скрипт и закрой его и посмотри меняются ли данные в БД.

У меня после закрытия скрипта какие то действия выполнялись в фоновом режиме, но не могу сказать отработал ли скрипт до конца.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Работа с соединениями](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/features.connection-handling.php)

Можно настроить, чтобы прерывался, можно настроить, чтобы НЕ прерывался.

Функция

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
```

Позволит продолжить выполнение даже если пользователь уже отключился.

Answer (score 1):

по стандарту, PHP - прогрузит скрипт, и будет его выполнять пока не выполнится, или пока не закончится общее время выделенное под каждый скрипт (время выполнение скрипта, настраивается в php.ini)

Answer (score 0):

Извините, но зачем, ЗАЧЕМ повторять этот цикл?! Зачем? Если при загрузке пользователем скрипт ОПЯТЬ пойдет на исполнение7

Вы раньше сервер положите, чем добьётесь желаемых резаультатов. И вообще - это форменное извращение.

Разбейте скрипт на части, когда нужно - вызывайте его аяксом, либо просто обращайтесь к нему. Не убивайте чужое оборудование и учитесь кодить грамотно, а не так, по извращенски.

И если не секрет, что же такого делает скрипт аж 30 минут? Расскажите, тут куча профессиональных программистов, которые Вам помогут сделать всё намного лучше.

Comment: Зачем - это второй вопрос. В первую очередь, если сам вопрос не дурацкий, имхо, стоит ответить именно на него. А в дополнение уже написать возможные способы улучшения идеи.

Comment: Это бы просто пример, суть вопроса была "выполнится ли скрипт или нет".